# How to decode string of curve data from XML

Tags: encoding, hex, decode

i have a Thormed spirometry measure file with manoeuvers and each other has curve data, which normally is represented as a chain of numerical values (separated by space, comma, semicolon etc). But this time i wasn't able to decode this string, it is **HEX** code but i stuck after decoding it from **HEX**. What should be the next step? String is inside "blob" tag

```
<!--Thormed Software generated XML file!-->    
<Table name="FVC_CURVE_DATA">
<Field name="ID" type="integer">1</Field>
<Field lengthInBytes="2856" name="DATA" type="blob">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</Field>
<Field name="VERSION" type="integer">1</Field>
<Field name="DATA_SIZE_IN_BYTES" type="integer">2856</Field>
<Field name="CRC1" type="integer">244</Field>
<Field name="CRC2" type="integer">136</Field>
<Field name="SAMPLING_TIME_SEC" type="single">0.010000</Field>
```

Decode from HEX is like:

```
ÇQéÇDâ!Ç}ä1Ç@åGÇÖêeÇ╙ïÅÇ#É─Ç╨öü]ÖPüQ¥óü9áⁿü▀ó[éMÑ┐éφª&â=¿ÅâE⌐·â¿⌐däb⌐═ä▐¿5àΘ¿₧à∩¿å▐ºfådª┼å╥ñçßórçΣá┬çFƒê╒¥WêM£¢ê╡Ü▄êCÖëÿTë≤ûîëΣò┬ë╪ö⌠ëÆô#è?ÆOè0æyèlÉíè▐Å╔èêÅ≡èQÅïΘÄ;ïVÄ^ï┐ìÇï8ìíï¬î└ï(î▐ï°ïⁿï╞ïîJï5îªèNîègî¼ëîiëùîDë»îNë╞î@ë▌î≡ê≤îzêì-êì ê1ìêEì╪çYì~çkì(ç}ìΩåÄì▐åáì≥å▓ìⁿå─ì∩å╒ì╚åµìáå÷ìråÄBåÄå%Ä╒à3ÄâàAÄTàNÄ@à\Ä2àhÄàuÄ╗äÇÄæäîÄääùÄäúÄtä«ÄXä╣Ä0ä├Ää═Äτâ╫ÄεâßÄ·âδÄⁿâ⌡Ä▌â■ÄÑâÅuâÅiâÅ{â"Å|â+Ånâ3Ågâ<ÅSâDÅ,âLÅâTÅâ\ÅâcÅ
```

Comment: I expect you know roughly what is in the blob? Have you tried writing any code to decode it?

Comment: I expecting for a chain like 1,2,64,767,888,998 etc.. but i have no idea how i can get there, may be someone is familiar with string like: ÇÇÇÇÇdÇÇΘÇÇöü

Comment: What is the possible range and resolution of the values? Minimum, maximum, increment between values? Do you know how many readings are in the blob? Or what is the duration of the recording, can work out the number of readings using the sampling time 0.01s

Comment: For this curve manoeuvre i've got  also this two parameters:
<Field name="FET" type="integer">6060</Field>
<Field name="ZEROTIME" type="integer">110</Field>
which can be usable.
FET is Forced Expiratory Time, but it seems i have to contact software manufacturer and ask for decoding algorithm.

Comment: Does this look plausible: https://ibb.co/dddNLa don't know what the units are, seems to be 714 pairs of values - so duration 7.14s.

Comment: Exactly! This string can be split in 4 bytes chunks, than just decoding this chunks to decimals i've got values, and was able to draw graphs on timeline. Thanks.